# Why is matillion not loading data from S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I have a simple S3 load with all the correct information. There are no validation errors but and the package executes without a problem. It's just that there is no data in the table. Any tips from someone that is knowledgeable about Matillion?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of reasons why Matillion might not appear to load any data in an S3 Load.

Firstly, I'd check that the pattern matches the file names in the S3 location, which is a regular expression match.
I believe that also includes the path which you may have included in the location parameter, so it may be worth modifying your pattern to look something like `.*\/FilePrefix.*` or even just `.*` and then selecting the actual file in the location parameter

Secondly, if the files were last modified more than 64 days ago, or they have already been loaded in to the table previously, Snowflake won't load them by default, which you can get around by turning the Force Load parameter On.